# Using "next" in an "iterator" and getting type mismatch error

Tags: scala, image-processing, iterator, type-mismatch

I am writing my code in Scala and need to have a loop over a vector of points in an image but getting type mismatch error!. I can understand why I have the error but I don't know how to solve it. here is my code:

```
  val output= new Mat (image.rows, image.cols,CV_8UC3,new Scalar(0, 0, 0))
  val it = Iterator(vect1)
  var vect3=new Array[Byte](3)
  vect3(0)=0
  vect3(1)=255.toByte
  vect3(2)=0
  var e= new Point(0,0)
  while(it.hasNext){
      e = it.next();
      output.put(e.x.toInt,e.y.toInt,vect3)
  }
```

and I am getting this error:

```
        ...
        type mismatch;
        found : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[org.opencv.core.Point]
        required: org.opencv.core.Point[
        e = it.next()
```

Comment: What type is `vect1`?

Comment: var vect1 = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Point]()

Comment: Is `it` supposed to iterate over the contents of `vect1`?  If so, you want `vect1.iterator`, not `Iterator(vect1)`.  `Iterator(a,b,c,...)` iterates over the elements you list one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `val it = Iterator(vect1)`, you are creating an iterator that iterates on `vect1` itself, and not on `vect1`'s elements. Thankfully, you don't need to create an iterator for that, because it already exists :

```
val vect1 = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
// vect1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
val it = vect1.iterator
// it: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
while (it.hasNext) {
  println(it.next)
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// res0: Unit = ()
```

Note that, according to the [Scala API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer), `ArrayBuffer` inherits from [IterableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.IterableLike). `IterableLike` basically means that a collection is iterable, so it makes sense that it defines a method which returns an iterator.

---

By the way, you can also avoid directly accessing the iterator entirely, using either the foreach method or a for comprehension, because `IterableLike` also defines the `foreach`method:

```
// foreach
vect1.foreach(p => output.put(p.x.toInt, p.y.toInt, vect3))
// for comprehension
for (p <- vect1) {
  output.put(p.x.toInt, p.y.toInt, vect3)
}
```

Using the foreach method or the for comprehension is strictly equivalent: the compiler translates for comprehensions to one or more method calls; in this case, a call to foreach.

Comment: Thank you so much for the brief explanation, Problem solved :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you're new to Scala collectionss, you should have a look at the [collections overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html) in the official documentation, it's very instructive. Scala's collections framework is really quite impressive once you get to know it!